# Issues when installing Laravel using composer

Tags: php, laravel, composer

Using Ubuntu 20.04 and PHP 8

When executing composer install for Laravel

```
Do not run Composer as root/super user! See https://getcomposer.org/root for details
Continue as root/super user [yes]? 
Composer is operating significantly slower than normal because you do not have the PHP curl extension enabled.
No composer.lock file present. Updating dependencies to latest instead of installing from lock file. See https://getcomposer.org/install for more information.
Loading composer repositories with package information
Info from https://repo.packagist.org: #StandWithUkraine
Updating dependencies
Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.

  Problem 1
    - phpunit/phpunit[9.5.10, ..., 9.5.x-dev] require ext-dom * -> it is missing from your system. Install or enable PHP's dom extension.
    - Root composer.json requires phpunit/phpunit ^9.5.10 -> satisfiable by phpunit/phpunit[9.5.10, ..., 9.5.x-dev].

To enable extensions, verify that they are enabled in your .ini files:
    - /etc/php/8.0/cli/php.ini
    - /etc/php/8.0/cli/conf.d/10-mysqlnd.ini
    - /etc/php/8.0/cli/conf.d/10-opcache.ini
    - /etc/php/8.0/cli/conf.d/10-pdo.ini
    - /etc/php/8.0/cli/conf.d/20-calendar.ini
    - /etc/php/8.0/cli/conf.d/20-ctype.ini
    - /etc/php/8.0/cli/conf.d/20-exif.ini
    - /etc/php/8.0/cli/conf.d/20-ffi.ini
    - /etc/php/8.0/cli/conf.d/20-fileinfo.ini
    - /etc/php/8.0/cli/conf.d/20-ftp.ini
    - /etc/php/8.0/cli/conf.d/20-gettext.ini
    - /etc/php/8.0/cli/conf.d/20-iconv.ini
    - /etc/php/8.0/cli/conf.d/20-mysqli.ini
    - /etc/php/8.0/cli/conf.d/20-pdo_mysql.ini
    - /etc/php/8.0/cli/conf.d/20-pdo_sqlite.ini
    - /etc/php/8.0/cli/conf.d/20-phar.ini
    - /etc/php/8.0/cli/conf.d/20-posix.ini
    - /etc/php/8.0/cli/conf.d/20-readline.ini
    - /etc/php/8.0/cli/conf.d/20-shmop.ini
    - /etc/php/8.0/cli/conf.d/20-sockets.ini
    - /etc/php/8.0/cli/conf.d/20-sqlite3.ini
    - /etc/php/8.0/cli/conf.d/20-sysvmsg.ini
    - /etc/php/8.0/cli/conf.d/20-sysvsem.ini
    - /etc/php/8.0/cli/conf.d/20-sysvshm.ini
    - /etc/php/8.0/cli/conf.d/20-tokenizer.ini
    - /etc/php/8.0/cli/conf.d/20-zip.ini
You can also run `php --ini` in a terminal to see which files are used by PHP in CLI mode.
Alternatively, you can run Composer with `--ignore-platform-req=ext-dom` to temporarily ignore these required extensions.
```

When I try to install sudo apt-get install php-mbstring or sudo apt install php-xml
or composer update I get the same error and I already have mbstring and xml installed

Answer (score 0):

First

```
sudo apt-get install php8.0-curl
```

Second

```
sudo apt-get install php-curl
```

Answer (score 0):

Composer error message states that one extension is not installed/enabled:

```
require ext-dom * -> it is missing from your system.
```

You can install it using this command:

```
sudo apt install php8.1-xml
```

Then enable it with this command:

```
sudo phpenmod xml
```